# Show that $|n\rangle$ is correctly normalized

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, normalization

> Prove that  $$|n\rangle = \frac1{\sqrt{n!}} (\hat a^\dagger)^n |0\rangle$$ is correctly normalized.

I know I must show its bra-ket equals 1 but I don't know what bra-ket notation really means, so I can't even do a beginning step

If $|n\rangle$ equals the expression above, what does $\langle n|n\rangle$ imply?

Comment: Why, then, are you not asking a question about what bra-ket notation really means (or better yet, googling it first and seeing how that goes)?

Comment: @WillO I did, I only saw integral equalities of <n|n>. But an integral will not lead to anywhere in this question, it must be something simpler

Comment: Is [this](http://www.pa.msu.edu/~mmoore/Lect22_CohStates.pdf) helpful ?

Comment: @Simon those notes implied <n|n>=1 around pg.7. is that always true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show that it is correctly normalised, you need to show that $| \left <n|n \right>|^2=1$ where in this case $\left <n \right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}  \left <0 \right| \hat a^n$. And here I suppose $\hat a$ is a ladder operator. Go take a look on this link to know more about ladder operators https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried that, how do I get rid of the <0|?

Comment: wait, i thought $\left <n \right|=\left <0 \right| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \hat a^n  $

Comment: First find $\left <0 \right | \hat a^n$ and then do the same for the dagger one this will help you. And yes you are right my 0 should be in front.

Comment: I can only do it for the dagger one. I don't how to do it for bra

Comment: Hint $\hat a^\dagger \left |0\right >=\sqrt{0+1} \left |0+1 \right >$ and you do this $n$ times and here will come your factorial.

Comment: I can't read that

Comment: Oh I see! Well it is like acting a dagger on the ket, but complex conjuguated.

Comment: And why is <0|0>=1?

Comment: Since it is the same state. The inner product of two identical states as to be 1 knowing that the inner product <b|a> corresponds to the probability amplitude that a system in state a turns into state b. Now, if you think about it if you have two identical states, it will obviously be 1 since the probability that a system in whatever state turns into that same state is 100% sure. Basically it is this.

Comment: Thanks! Please have a look at this http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216301/prove-identity-about-coherent-state

Answer (score 1):

$\langle n| n\rangle = \frac{1}{n!} \langle0|(a)^n (a^{\dagger})^n |0\rangle$

Because $(a^{\dagger})^n |0\rangle = \sqrt{n!} |n\rangle$ and $(a)^n |n\rangle =\sqrt{n!} |0\rangle $

So we have $\langle n| n\rangle = \langle 0| 0\rangle =1 $

In fact, I think the reasonable process is to assume the normalized $\langle n| n\rangle =1 $ first, then we get the calculation of operators $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$.

Comment: cool, and why is <0|0>=1?

Comment: @minusatwelfth See my edition, I think we should first assume a normalization first.

Comment: The question is asking to prove <n|n>=1 though. <0|0> is a special case of that which means I cannot assume it's true, unless there is a reason

Comment: @minusatwelfth Because $|0\rangle$ is the ground state, you can always assume it is normalized, if it's not, then absorb some constants to make it be.